# moved to dedicated virtual server, having trouble with .htaccess and permissions

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, permissions

Working with cakePHP

My index.php is in www.domain.com/httpdocs/sub/app/webroot

Previously, on shared hosting I just replaced "domain.com/" with "domain.com/app+core directories" (without httpdocs/ or sub/)

I've moved to media temple dedicated virtual server and am hitting a 403 forbidden error: 
    "You don't have permission to access /sub/ on this server."

Permission is set to 755 for sub/ directory

In domain.com/sub/app -> .htaccess file:

Code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /sub/app/
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

In domain.com/sub/app/webroot -> .htaccess file:

Code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /sub/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried:
Right now httpdocs/ contains blank index.html and simple redirect:

```
Redirect /index.html http://domain.com/sub/
```

Creating another .htaccess file for /sub, but that seemed to confound things further.

I'm on media temple, followed this article: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/403_Forbidden_error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Noticed you were having some issues with your (dv). We just wanted to let you know that we are here to help you with any problems that you may have. If you keep running into these errors, please open up a Support Request so we can help you out.